# understanding for functional delta method

Tags: bootstrap, delta-method

I am confusing about the *functional delta method*, this method states that,

$$ \sqrt{n}[\phi(\mathbb{P}_n) - \phi(\mathbb{P})] $$ weakly converges in $B$ to $\phi'(\mathbb{G})$, whenever $\mathcal{F}$ is Donsker and $\phi: l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow B$ is *Hadamard differential*.

In my understanding, this method is used to extend the Donker theorem (functional perspective) to find the confidence band for specific statistic which do not have the form $\{\mathbb{P}_{n}f, f \in \mathcal{F} \}$ but can be express as $\phi(\mathbb{P}_n)$.

**Question**: For example, can anybody give me the exactly form $\phi$ (including $B$) for sample quantile process, i.e.
$$\xi_n(p) = \mathbb{F}_{n}^{-1}(p)$$